# Camera Clipping through Mesh Plane Causes Visible Clipping in Render

Tags: rendering, texturing, camera

I'm animating an infinite loop with a camera zooming out from a tiled image that then forms into a whole version of the tiled image.  Here's the blend:

[image]

I'm using Blender Internal.  Though not refined yet, I have the animation done, but when I go to render a png test, this happens on frames 7 and 13, and so on throughout the loop:

[image: what a lovely clip]

Obviously this is not cool.  I'm assuming it has to do with the fact that the camera "cuts" through the mesh plane my texture is on, which is causing some clipping.  I've done this effect with other projects, however, and I've never had this issue (granted it was with other software).  I thought it might have something to do with the clipping distance on my camera, but playing with the values hasn't proved successful.  Any ideas?

EDIT: I tried just keeping the camera in place and scaling the textured plane instead, but the problem still persists.  Perhaps it's a texturing issue?

Comment: I don't think it's something related with the texture, it happens also with only the camera and a brand new plane. You can fix this by slightly rotating the Repeating plane on the Z axis by a little fraction of degree (e.g. 0.0001), but it would be interesting to know why it happens.

Comment: Hm, strange!  Maybe someday someone will have an answer, but for now, this quick fix does the trick! Thank you!

Comment: It seems to be sky seen through - on [these 2 images is shown](https://imgur.com/a/ECy4z) what happens if world background color changed to gray on the 1-st, and if Alpha in **Render** > **Shanding** scroll changed to *Transparent* - on 2-nd. I thought this is Z-fighting, but I'm pretty sure it really isn't (as I tried to make it reveal itself, to no avail). So I don't see any reasons this to happen.